# Vertically Space "Weight" between Linear Layout Buttons

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-activity

[image]

I was wondering how to add space between buttons vertically, I was following instructor and the buttons on his screen seems good. Also, when I downloaded his project files the problem still facing me.

I am new to this weight technology in XML.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="#EFEFEF"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:maxLength="12"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSeven"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7"
            android:onClick="onDigit"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEight"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="8"
            android:onClick="onDigit"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9"
            android:onClick="onDigit"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDivide"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="/"
            android:onClick="onDigit"
            />



    </LinearLayout>
      
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try replacing Button with androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### you want to add margin between buttons in weighted view or any other type of view. The solution is you want to add the line which i have written below.

---

### for horizontal margin

```
android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp" 
<!--change the dp size prefered your design-->
```

### for vertical margin

```
android:layout_marginVertical="5dp" 
<!--change the dp size prefered your design-->
```

---

### or if you preferly want to set margin to left, top, right, bottom.

---

### for left, top, right, bottom margin

```
<!--left-->
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
<!--change the dp size prefered your design-->

<!--top-->
android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
<!--change the dp size prefered your design-->

<!--right-->
android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
<!--change the dp size prefered your design-->

<!--bottom-->
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" 
<!--change the dp size prefered your design-->
```

---

if, I solved your problem please give tick mark & up-vote this answer. Thanks in advance. ;)